# How to dynamically render an element after scrolling to a certain position in a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, dom-events

I would like my "emailForm" component to render on my Navbar after user scrolled to beginning of "laundry section", does someone know how to do that?

I tried `{window.scrollY > 500px ? EmailForm : "" }`
But it doesn't work, I am not very familiar yet with react so maybe you could help me figure out the right method to achieve it?

Container:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, {Component} from 'react';


// Components
import Section from '../components/styledComponents/section';
import EmailForm from "../components/emailForm"
import Navbar from './containers/navbar';

export default class Individuals extends Component {


 render() {
  const { iconStyle } = this;
  return (
      <NavBar/>
   <main className="individuals">
    {/*Header section*/}
    <Section height="100vh" usedScreen="84px" className="your-laundromat-connected">
       <div className="title">
        <h1>
         Title</span>.
        </h1>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div className="subscribe-container">
      <div className="catchphrase-input">Prévenez-moi :</div>
      <EmailForm/>
      </div>
     </div>
    </Section>

    {/*Laundry section*/}
    <div className="container-laverie">
    <h2>Votre temps est précieux. Utilisez-le autrement.</h2>
                <p>Finie l'attente interminable à la laverie... grâce à l'application Lavigo vous reprenez le contrôle sur votre emploi du temps.</p>
     {/* </div>  */}
    </div>
   </main>

  );
 }
}
```

NavBar component:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react';
import INavbarState from '../containers/interfaces/Inavbar';
//Librairies
import $ from 'jquery'
import EmailForm from '../components/emailForm'


export default class Individuals extends React.PureComponent<{}, INavbarState | any> {
 constructor(props: INavbarState | any) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    showMenu: false,
    scrollTop: true
  };
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  const that = this;
  let $win = $(window);
 
  $win.scroll(function () {
    if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
   if (!that.state.scrollTop) {
     that.setState({ scrollTop: true })
   }
    } else {
   if (that.state.scrollTop) {
     that.setState({ scrollTop: false })
   }
    }
  });

  if(window.innerWidth <= 1024)
  {
    that.setState({showMenu:false})
   // hide menubar
  }else{
    that.setState({showMenu:true})
     // show menubar
  }

   window.onresize = function(event:any) {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 1024)
  {
    that.setState({showMenu:false})
   // hide menubar
  }else{
    that.setState({showMenu:true})
     // show menubar
  }

    if (window.scrollY > 1000) {

    }  
   };



   ontoggle = () => {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 1024)
    {
   this.setState({ showMenu: !this.state.showMenu })
     // hide menubar
    }else{
   this.setState({showMenu:true})
    // show menubar
    }
   }
 }

 render() {
 return (
  <nav className="nav">
   <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div className="container-email">
    <EmailForm/> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi check this ScrollExample and ScrollChild Component. I used ScrollChild in ScrollExample Component. When you scroll down upto 200 then it will show ScrollChild Component on the screen.

**ScrollExample Component**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ScrollChild from "./ScrollChild";

export default class ScrollExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChildActive: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    handleScroll = (event) => {
        let scrollTop = window.scrollY;

        if (scrollTop > 200)
            this.setState({isChildActive: true});
        else
            this.setState({isChildActive: false});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{height: 2000}}>
                Scroll down to show the EmailForm
                {
                    this.state.isChildActive ? <ScrollChild/> : null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ScrollChild Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function ScrollChild(props) {
    return (
        <div style={{backgroundColor: '#1569C7', color: '#ffffff', width: 500, marginTop: 300, padding: 20}}>
            THIS IS A DUMMY TEXT
            <h1>How to dynamically render an element after scrolling to a certain position in a page?</h1>

            I would like my "emailForm" component to render on my Navbar after user scrolled to beginning of
            "laundry section", does someone know how to do that?

            I tried window.scrollY > 500px ? EmailForm : "" But it doesn't work, I am not very familiar yet with
            react so maybe you could help me figure out the right method to achieve it?

            I would like my "emailForm" component to render on my Navbar after user scrolled to beginning of
            "laundry section", does someone know how to do that?

            I tried window.scrollY > 500px ? EmailForm : "" But it doesn't work, I am not very familiar yet with
            react so maybe you could help me figure out the right method to achieve it?

            I would like my "emailForm" component to render on my Navbar after user scrolled to beginning of
            "laundry section", does someone know how to do that?

            I tried window.scrollY > 500px ? EmailForm : "" But it doesn't work, I am not very familiar yet with
            react so maybe you could help me figure out the right method to achieve it?

            I would like my "emailForm" component to render on my Navbar after user scrolled to beginning of
            "laundry section", does someone know how to do that?

            I tried window.scrollY > 500px ? EmailForm : "" But it doesn't work, I am not very familiar yet with
            react so maybe you could help me figure out the right method to achieve it?
        </div>
    );
}

export default ScrollChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time your state changes, it will call your component's render. Yet in your render, nothing will change, because your render does not rely on `this.state.scrollTop`

To fix this, you need to do two things:
1. Update the state when the user scrolls past the threshold (500px)
2. Use this new state value inside your `render()` method, to re-render the component.

I've created an example where I change the form's opacity when `this.state.showEmailForm` changes. You can see and the below the example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  showEmailForm: false,
};
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  };

  onScroll = () => {
this.setState({
  showEmailForm: window.scrollY > 500,
});
  };

  render() {
return (
  <div className="app">
    <p>
      {" "}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Sed aliquet
      iaculis tellus id faucibus.Sed pellentesque sit amet tortor a
      mattis.Nullam ligula ante, condimentum eget ipsum vitae, fringilla
      consequat lorem.Aliquam vitae enim sem.Morbi consequat quam vel
      faucibus blandit.Fusce tempus fringilla neque sit amet eleifend.Nullam
      enim augue, facilisis a vehicula id, malesuada ut sapien.Curabitur vel
      dui ut risus placerat eleifend.Maecenas pulvinar magna ante, a congue
      nibh laoreet id.In consectetur viverra ligula, a mattis dolor blandit
      id.Aliquam ante massa, sollicitudin eget augue id, malesuada fringilla
      sem.Sed viverra pretium dignissim.Morbi ut volutpat ante, sed
      tincidunt quam.Praesent placerat, ipsum commodo venenatis sodales,
      tellus ante pellentesque ante, ac ultrices massa velit et velit.{" "}
    </p>
    <form
      style={{
        opacity: this.state.showEmailForm ? 1 : 0,
      }}
    >
      <label>
        Name <br />
        <input type="text" />
      </label>

      <label>
        Email <br />
        <input type="email" />
      </label>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
);
  }
}

const rootElement = document.querySelector("#container");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.app {
  height: 1000vh;
  background: palevioletred;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form {
  padding: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an example code now, but you can do something like this:
On scrolling you can check if the element is visible (with position and scroll position). If it is, you can do a jQuery animation